# On the global section of tensor product of two vector bundles on a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex algebraic surface of degree $d \geq 5$ in $\mathbb P^3$. Let $H$ be the hyperplane class. Let $E_1, E_2$ be two slope stable  vector bundles (w.r.to $H$) on $X$ of rank $2$ and $2r$ (where, $r \geq 1$) respectively. Let's assume that, $c_1(E_2 \otimes E^*_1) =0$. Then my question is: Are the following true

$(i)$ $h^0(E_2 \otimes E^*_1) =0$ and

$(ii)$ $h^2(E_2 \otimes E^*_1) =0$?

For $(i)$  we see that if $E_2 \otimes E^*_1$ is slope stable, then if $h^0(E_2 \otimes E^*_1) \neq 0$, then there exists an injection $\mathcal O_X \hookrightarrow E_2 \otimes E^*_1$ and by slope computation we get a contradiction to stability. But we only know that $E_2 \otimes E^*_1$ is slope semistable. Can we really say that it's stable?

For $(ii)$ By Serre duality, $h^2(E_2 \otimes E^*_1) \cong h^0(E_1 \otimes E^*_2 \otimes \mathcal O_X(d-4))$, where things get even worse.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
H^0(X, E_2 \otimes E_1^*) \cong Hom(E_1,E_2).
$$
Now $E_1$ and $E_2$ are stable (by your assumption), and the condition on $c_1$ means that they have the same slope. Therefore, there are no morphisms between them, hence the space is zero. The case of the second space is analogous.

Comment: for the second case,$H^0(E_1 \otimes E^*_2 \otimes \mathcal O_X(d-4)) \cong Hom(E_2, E_1 \otimes \mathcal O_X(d-4))$. But I have $C_1(E_1 \otimes E^*_2 \otimes \mathcal O_X(d-4)) \neq 0$. In this case, the slopes are not same. Does that mean $h^2(E_2 \otimes E^*_1) \neq 0$?

Comment: This is possible.